# Dynamically Creating Functions and Binding Buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, dynamic, tkinter

I am trying to assign values to buttons which return their value when clicked (more precisely, they print it.) The only caveat is that the buttons are created dynamically, using a for loop.

How can I assign id's (and other variables) to buttons which have been created with a for loop?

Example Code:

```
#Example program to illustrate my issue with dynamic buttons.

from Tkinter import *

class my_app(Frame):
    """Basic Frame"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        """Init the Frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.Create_Widgets()

    def Create_Widgets(self):

        for i in range(1, 11): #Start creating buttons

            self.button_id = i #This is meant to be the ID. How can I "attach" or "bind" it to the button?
            print self.button_id

            self.newmessage = Button(self, #I want to bind the self.button_id to each button, so that it prints its number when clicked.
                                     text = "Button ID: %d" % (self.button_id),
                                     anchor = W, command =  lambda: self.access(self.button_id))#Run the method

            #Placing
            self.newmessage.config(height = 3, width = 100)
            self.newmessage.grid(column = 0, row = i, sticky = NW)

    def access(self, b_id): #This is one of the areas where I need help. I want this to return the number of the button clicked.
        self.b_id = b_id
        print self.b_id #Print Button ID

#Root Stuff


root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter Dynamics")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = my_app(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the last value of `self.button_id` when you call the command once the buttons are created. You have to bind the current value of the local variable for each lambda with `lambda i=i: do_something_with(i)`:

```
def Create_Widgets(self):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        self.newmessage = Button(self, text= "Button ID: %d" % i, anchor=W,
                                 command = lambda i=i: self.access(i))
        self.newmessage.config(height = 3, width = 100)
        self.newmessage.grid(column = 0, row = i, sticky = NW)
```